# Unknown SMD Component

Tags: pcb, identification, surface-mount, markings

I'm trying to find the components of the PCB I have. I have a problem with a 5 pin (SOT23-5) component. Can someone help me with this?

There are version1, version2 and version3 of the PCB and marking codes are AA43, AA44 and AACB respectively.

There is a reset button and an error switch on the board. I measured the voltage values ​​when I pressed any of them (see schematic.)

[image: PCB]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Props for a readable schematic imaged with something better than a potato, and for nailing the important signal levels and such. Good job!

Comment: Once you've contributed a question to this site, it gets kept for the benefit of future readers, which is allowed by the Terms of Service you agree to before contributing.  No destroying the question.

Comment: I rolled back your editing. There is no reason you deleted the schematic and the photo. You also got lots of upvotes because of that. I fully agree with @BenVoigt.

Comment: If you deleted that schematic and that photo because you want to preserve some IP right, well, sorry: this is not a free design service. When you post something here you relinquish some rights about the things you post (see the license and terms of service).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual search from s-manuals (https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/aa) didn't bring useful results.

The part looks like a low voltage op amp judging from the schematic. The right-hand side sub-circuit looks like a low-pass filtered non-inverting amplifier which converts the load current of the top-right NMOS to voltage. And the output goes to MCU (probably to ADC) through another RC low-pass filter. The other sub-circuit to the left is a buffer which gets its input from MCU/1.24V through a RC filter+divider and generates a reference/bias voltage for the amplifier stage for accurate/sensitive current measurement.

So what you can do is to search single low-voltage op amps with SOT-23-5 package from Digikey, Mouser, etc. and check their markings.

Answer (score 7):

This is roughly how that circuit can be re-drawn:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBjXsu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And here is it re-drawn to be easier to follow:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZO0PD.png)</sup>